# symfony 4 - Change logger output path

Tags: php, logging, symfony4

I got an error 500 on production env so I spent a lot of time to search where error was displaying. I found that symfony log errors using [logger](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Log/Logger.php) who send output to stderr by default so apache's error log is used in my case. I want to send messages to symfony's `env.log` (e.g `var/log/dev.log` and `var/log/prod.log`)

Documentation says :

> The minimum log level, the default output and the log format can also be changed by passing the appropriate arguments to the constructor of Logger. To do so, override the "logger" service definition.

But I can't figure out how I can change logger's output, for testing purpose I changed logger construct in `vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Log/Logger.php` as following with success:

```
public function __construct(string $minLevel = null, $output = 'abspath/to/project/var/log/dev.log', callable $formatter = null)
```

but I can't edit files in vendor dir.

So How I can override the "logger" service definition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not edit the vendor files. Those are included by composer, and overwriten on each install/update.

If you want to change the log path you can do this with using monolog and [config](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html#handlers-writing-logs-to-different-locations)

```
composer require symfony/monolog-bundle


monolog:
    handlers:
        # this "file_log" key could be anything
        file_log:
            type: stream
            # log to var/log/(environment).log
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log" #change path here
            # log *all* messages (debug is lowest level)
            level: debug

        syslog_handler:
            type: syslog
            # log error-level messages and higher
            level: error
```

Comment: As I said in my post , I can’t edit files in vendor meaning of courses I’ll not edit those. And I’m not using monolog but thx

Comment: As stated on the symfony page i linked, there is no other on board way to do this. So i hope that someone might be able to help you with this.

Comment: I tried to install monolog-bundle and add monolog.yaml as described in cookbook but it's not working, nothing has been write into `%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log`

Comment: I got this error ` There is no extension able to load the configuration for "monolog" (in "/config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml"). Looked for name
space "monolog", found ""doctrine_cache", "doctrine", "doctrine_migrations"
, "framework", "twig", "twig_extra", "security"" in /config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml")`

Comment: Did you clear your cache afterwards? Could be that some setting is stored and does not change. Does your php have write permissions on the target path?

Comment: That error message says that the monolog bundle is missing for bundles.php if you are not using symfony flex you have to add this manually:
Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],

Comment: I use flex why I would not ? :) After remove then install monolog bundle all is working. thanks